# How to apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma to the Hausdorff distance between a uniform sample on $[0,1]$ and the aforementioned interval

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $n\in\mathbb Z^+$ and $X_1\ldots X_n$ i.i.d. $\operatorname{Unif}[0,1]$, that is, an independent sample from a uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$.

I've spent way too much time trying to prove that, for any $\varepsilon\in\mathbb R^+$,

$\operatorname{P}\{d_H(\chi_n,[0,1])>\varepsilon\;\text{ i. o.}\}=0.$

The LHS on the previous inequality refers to the Hausdorff distance  between the sets $[0, 1]$ and $\chi_n:=\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$. In addition, by *i .o.* I mean *infinitely often*, as usual.

I've reduced this to the slightly simpler statement:

$\displaystyle\operatorname{P}\left\lbrace\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\min_{i=1\ldots n}|X_i-x|>\varepsilon\;\text{ i. o.}\right\rbrace=0,$

which I also know to be true.

So my main goal rn is proving this last claim, which is driving me crazy, although I do I know how to do it if I delete the supremum and use an arbitrary $x\in[0,1]$.

I've tried lots of things, which I don't want to disclose for the moment, in order not to "corrupt" your minds. Anyway, if anybody can give me some (explicit) hints, I'd me most grateful, for it's *almost sure* that I'm not going to figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I came up with a rather convoluted way to solve the problem, which basically consists in adapting the proof of theorem 3 in http://sci-hub.cc/10.1239/aap/1086957575, in case anyone's interested.

But I still feel that there must be some simple way to do it, probably in the same line of Nate Eldredge's hints.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: $d_H(\chi_n, [0,1])$ is monotone decreasing in $n$ (since $\chi_n$ just adds more points as $n$ increases).  So the limit as $n \to \infty$ exists, and your claim is equivalent to showing it equals 0 almost surely.

Hint 2: If $\omega$ is such that $\lim d_H(\chi_n(\omega), [0,1]) > 1/k$, then there exists an interval $(a,b)$, having rational endpoints and of length $> 1/(2k)$, such that no $X_n$ is in $(a,b)$.  What is the probability of that?

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your reply... But I'm afraid your overestimating my abilities. :/ I understand hint 1, but I don't know how to answer the question on hint 2. Could anybody elaborate it further?

Comment: Well, actually I think that probability is $<(1-1/(2k))^n$, but Idk what to do next.

Comment: And I guess that holds for all $n$, so the probability is $0$?

Comment: But I still don't get why you're taking $a,b\in\mathbb Q$.